# glm with nested treatments

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, nested-data

I am currently doing the statistical analysis for my master thesis.
In my experiment, I have 3 species that I expose to Erosion treatments.
After every treatment, I see what percentage of each species fall under one of 11 damage categories as can be seen in the picture:

[image]
I collected how big the angle compared to standing upright was. If the number was 5 for example, it was heavily leaning to the right. Angle_cat is just the damage category, sorry for not naming it properly. For the percentages, I looked at all shoots of the same plant species after an erosion treatment and calculated how much percentage of the plant fell under this damage category. So in the picture, all the percentages of Phrag (which is reed) and an erosion of 0 cm amount to 1. So for the Phrag 2.5 cm erosion, you can see that the percentage of species with an angle of -3 decreased.
The problem I currently have is that for each Erosion;Species combinations, I have multiple damage categories. So if I do glm(Percentage~Erosion*Species) all percentages would be like different experiment results of the same treatment, instead of a part of the results. Is there a way I can look at the difference between the different Erosion;Species;damage categories with a glm or do I need a different method?
Another way of representing this data is like this (if this helps):
[image]

I wish you a nice easter,
Sam

Comment: You say that there are 5 damage categories. Can you explain what `angle_cat` is? There seem to be 11 categories in the `angle_cat` column. Also, can you clarify what data you collected and how you compute the percentages?

Comment: I collected how big the angle compared to standing upright was. If the number was 5 for example, it was heavily leaning to the right. Angle_cat is just the damage category sorry for not naming it properly. For the percentages, I looked at all shoots of the same plant species after an erosion treatment and calculated how much percentage of the plant fell under this damage category. So in the picture all the percentages of Phrag (which is reed) and an erosion of 0 cm amount to 1. So for the Phrag 2.5 cm erosion you can see that the percentage of species with an angle of -3 decreased.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and for editing your question. So if I understand correctly, percentage is calculated as *number of shoots in angle category / total number of shoots*. Do you have the original numbers/counts?

Comment: Yes I do, do you need them?

Comment: I asked about the counts as I'm wondering whether multinomial regression might be appropriate or not. How many data points do you have for each combination of (Species, Erosion, angle_cat)?

Comment: Also, I don't understand how the percentage of species with angle -3 decreased. Isn't it 0 in the erosion = 0 row and also in the erosion = 2.5 row?

Comment: I mean that in  the -2(sorry my mistake) category the percentage changed from 0.06 percen of the total shoots to 0.028 when increasing the erosion from 0 to 2.5.

Comment: For each combination of Species, Erosion, angle_cat I have one measurement. The main issue I is that all the percentages are linked to an angle_cat which makes it more difficult than what I am used to. I added a picture in the question that will hopefully make it clearer)

Comment: Thanks for the edits, they are helpful. However, I'm not sure how you would fit a statistical model to this data as you have no replicates, ie. you have a single observation for each (Species, Erosion, Angle) combination. Let's take a simpler situation as an example: one categorical predictor X with 3 possible levels "a", "b", "c" and a continuous outcome Y. We can model this with a linear regression Y ~ X. But we cannot fit this regression if we only have three data points `(y1, x="a"), (y2,x="b"), (y3,x="c")`.

Comment: If you ignore the Species factor, then you get three data points per (Erosion, Angle) combination and then perhaps you can fit a model to the data. But just looking at the data table, the species don't look to be "similar" in their response to erosion.

Comment: You can always look at appropriate (visual) summaries of your data, and perhaps use those to formulate some hypotheses. But without replication (ie. observing the same phenomenon repeatedly under the same conditions/settings) you cannot estimate the variability (calculate standard errors, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for helping me. But isn't the repeated phenomenon in the percentage. Because each shoot is a repeat of an erosion treatment

Comment: Does it make sense to assume that the shoots independent replicates? If yes, then your observations are the shoots, not the percentages in each category, and you can use multinomial regression. See this [introduction](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/) for example.

Comment: The shoots can be seen as an independent replicate for the same erosion  but they are also used for the next erosion treatment. This  means that now I have made a data set with eact shoot indivdualy I have to add an ID column.  Whith that in mind I tried doing this : lm22 <- lmer(angle_cat ~ Erosion*Species+(1|ID)) (which works without "Hanging" and "dislodged") but becasue of "Hanging" and "dislodged" being non numeric I get an error  (Error in mkRespMod(fr, REML = REMLpass) : response must be numeric).

Comment: What about treating the angles are ordered categories? The number-labeled angle categories are already ordered; can it make sense to assign an order to the remaining two categories? Then you'll have ordinal regression. Here is a tutorial about it: https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/

Comment: Okey that worked. Thank you for your help !!